# Size of a structure having unsigned short ints

Tags: c++, c, bit-fields

I was surfing in one of our organisational data documents and I came across the following piece of code.

```
struct A {
 unsigned short int i:1;
 unsigned short int j:1;
 unsigned short int k:14;
};


int main(){
 A aa;
 int n = sizeof(aa);
 cout << n;
}
```

Initially I thought the size will be 6 bytes as the size of the unsigned short int is 2 bytes. but the output of the above code was 2 bytes(On visual studio 2008).

Is there a slight possibility that the `i:1`, `j:1` and `k:14` makes it a bit field or something? Its just a guess and I am not very sure about it. Can somebody please help me in this?

Comment: This is a bit fields. Size is 16 bit. This question is very wide and have been explained a lot of times in the books.

Comment: You guessed correctly, this is syntax for bitfields. You could have easily verified that by checking the reference for bitfields in c or c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is `bitfield`, indeed.

<del>Well, i'm not very much sure about `c++`, but</del> In `c99` standard, as per  chapter 6.7.2.1 (10):

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next bits or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.

That makes your structure size (1 bit + 1 bit + 14 bits) = 16 bits = 2 bytes.

Note: No structure padding is considered here.

---

Edit:

As per `C++14` standard, chapter §9.7,

> A member-declarator of the form
>
> identifier<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>: constant-expression
>
> specifies a bit-field; its length is set off from the bit-field name by a colon. [...] Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is
> implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined. Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit.

Comment: It's *at least* 2 bytes big.